# conversion of XML into jaxb model

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

below is my xml, I want to produce jaxb model out of that, my goal is to extract data 
   from item node. what annotations should be used or 
   how my jaxb model class will look? thanks in advance.

```
<channel>
    <title>VIAF Search: Roy Tennant</title>
    <link>...</link>
    <description>VIAF: Results of search: cql.any all Roy Tennant</description>
    <opensearch:totalResults>8</opensearch:totalResults>
    <opensearch:startIndex>1</opensearch:startIndex>
    <opensearch:itemsPerPage>8</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
    <opensearch:link type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" 
                     href="http://viaf.org/allFieldsSearch.xml"
                     rel="search"/>
    <opensearch:Query searchTerms="Roy Tennant" role="request"/>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>
        <title>Tennant, Jeff</title>
        <link>http://viaf.org/viaf/41080217</link>
        <pubDate>Mon, 22 Feb 2010 06:44:19 GMT</pubDate>
        <guid>http://viaf.org/viaf/41080217</guid>
    </item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
</channel>
```

Comment: The following will help:  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted

Comment: sorry there is no </rss> tag in the end

Answer (score 0):

Update:

### This post is for you: http://chawlasandeep.com/jaxb-a-head-start/

This looks like RSS, the schema is here http://rss2schema.codeplex.com/releases/view/18981

Next generate model from schema, for example in maven

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <packageName>com.example.myschema</packageName> <!-- The name of your generated source package -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This generate all needed JAXB classes with required annotations.